# Is it needed to regularize in case you know your data is generated by a model of your model class?

Tags: machine-learning, kernel-trick, regularization, ridge-regression, statistical-learning

Assume we have a dataset $X_{full}$ with labels $y_{full}$. We train a kernel ridge regression model on this data with the Gaussian kernel. This model is used to generate predictions on the whole dataset $X_{full}$, the predictions are given by $\hat{y}_{full}$. This model uses a regularization parameter $\lambda$. 
The kernel ridge regression model that I use is minimizes the following in the featurespace of the Gaussian kernel:
$$\frac{1}{N} \sum_1^N (\hat{y}-y)^2 + \lambda ||w||^2_K$$
So note it minimizes the mean squared error(!). Because of this it is possible to show that our model will always have $||w||^2_K \leq \frac{1}{\lambda}$.

Now we obtain a subset of the data, $X$ and a subset of the corresponding predicted labels $\hat{y}$. We know the labels $\hat{y}$ are given by $\hat{y} = w^T x$ in the featurespace of the kernel, where $w$ is the model trained above. Let's call this model the oracle model.

On this subset of the data we are going to train a kernel ridge regression model. To train this model we use the set $X$, $\hat{y}$, thus we use the outputs of the oracle model as labels to train this model. We want this model to generalize as well as possible to the whole dataset $X_{full}$ in terms of the squared error with respect to the labels $\hat{y}_{full}$.

Given a (small) training sample $X$,$\hat{y}$, is it then better to train the model with the same regularization parameter as the oracle model, or is it better to regularize less?

For kernel ridge regression we require a small regularization term in order to fit the model, for example if we use the Gaussian kernel we can only train it if we have a small lambda, otherwise we might be unable to invert the kernel matrix.
So we could use a different $\lambda$, for example make it small enough so we can still invert the kernel matrix (for example we can use the pseudo-inverse). Is this then better than training with the same regularization parameter as the oracle model? The question here of course becomes: how to compute the pseudo-inverse, or how do we set the regularization parameter smaller than $\lambda$ that does not introduce numerical difficulties...

My intuition tells me that a small regularization parameter will be better, since we can then fit $w$ better: if we regularize we introduce bias in estimating $w$. However, on the other hand, if we make the regularization parameter smaller, we are essentially using a too complex model to fit the data, therefore we might expect it to generalize worse: the training procedure might estimate a $\hat{w}$ for example with much larger norm than $w$ since we constrain the norm of $\hat{w}$ less.